# Bootstrap not working in view files in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm a new user of `Laravel 5.2`. Laravel 5.2 uses `bootstrap 3.3.6`

I tried to add bootstrap `tooltip` in view files, but it doesn't work

when i test the script below, it shows that jquery doesn't work :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

so I tested :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

also it didn't work! but when I test just:

```
alert('hello');
```

it works

at `app.blade.php` i have something like this:

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
{{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
```

and at the head tag I have :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: Where did you place the scripts? Did you extend the app.blade.php view in your own view? Are the assets actually in your assets/js & assets/css folder? Are jQuery and Bootstrap actually loaded? Check your console.

Comment: @Frank Provost all you question answer is Yes. but it not working. when i add jquery $().... under bottom it work but when add in view files it dont work!

Comment: what do you mean with "under bottom" ? Where do you add your stuff?

Comment: Can you maybe provide a full example of how you use jquery? Post your view which does not work.